# covert sql zend framework 1 to zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

I have SQL statement of zf1 follow:

```
 $tableName = 'log_ccu_' . $gameId;
    $sql = 'SELECT MAX(su) AS total ';
    $sql .= 'FROM ';
    $sql .= '(SELECT SUM(ccu) AS su ';
    $sql .= 'FROM ' . $tableName . ' WHERE `time` BETWEEN "' . $startMoment . '" AND "' . $endMoment . '" ' . $_where . $where;
    $sql .= 'GROUP BY time) AS p ';
    $stmt = $this->_ccuMobileDb->query($sql);
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
```

Now i want convert it to zf2 use select tablegateway.I try this but not working:

```
$tableName = 'log_ccu_' . $gameId;
    $apdater = ServiceLocatorFactory::getInstance()->get("Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter");
    $tableGateway = new TableGateway($tableName, $apdater);
    $select = $tableGateway->getSql()->select();
    $subSql = $tableGateway()->getSQl()->select();
    $subSql->columns(['su'=>new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression('SUM(ccu)')])->where([new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Between('time',$startMoment,$endMoment)]);
    $sub = $subSql->getSqlString($adapter->getPlatform());
    $select->column(['total'=> new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression($sub)]);
```

Comment: So what is the problem exactly? Does the first statement work? What error does the second statement gives you?

Comment: This error:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException' with message